# linear operator on inner product space with $(B,A)=\operatorname{tr}(AB^\dagger)$

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, trace

In the linear space of $n \times n$ matrices on $\mathbb{C}$ consider:
$$(B,A)=tr(AB^\dagger)$$

1. Prove that it's a Hilbert product (inner product)
2. Show a orthogonal base for the space
3. if we have a linear operator so defined:
   $$ \mathcal H: B \to H^\dagger BH$$
   then get $\mathcal H^\dagger$
4. If H is a unitary matrix, get the norm of $\mathcal H$

**1)** I've tried to use the definition of inner product:

i) $(B,B)=tr(BB^\dagger)= \sum_{i=1}^n b_{ii} \overline{b_{ii}}=\sum_{i=1}^n |b_{ii}|^2 >0 $

ii) $(B,A+C)=tr((A+C)B^\dagger)= \sum_{i=1}^n (a_{ii}+c_{ii}) \overline{b_{ii}}=(B,A)+(B,C) $

iii) the same with scalar: $(B,\lambda A)= \lambda(B,A)$

i) $\overline{(B,A)}=tr \overline{(AB^\dagger)}=tr(\overline{A}B)=(A,B)$

**2)** I think that an orthogonal base could be: $\{E_i\}_{i=1}^n$ with $$E_1= diag(1, 0, 0, ...)$$
$$E_2=diag(0, 1, 0, ...)$$
etc, so that: $(E_i, E_j)=0$  $\forall i \neq j$

**3) Here I have the biggest troubles.** I'm looking for the self adjoint operator of $ \mathcal H $:
$$(\mathcal H B,A)=(B,\mathcal H ^\dagger A)$$
$$(H^\dagger BH, A)= \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ii} \overline{\overline{h_{ii}}h_{ii}b_{ii}}=\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ii} \overline{b_{ii}} |h_{ii}|^2$$
And I think that $\mathcal H^\dagger$ could be:
$$\mathcal H^\dagger: A \to HAH^\dagger$$

**4)** Being $H$ unitary it preserves the distances (hence the norm). So we have:
$$||\mathcal H B||=||B||$$
The norm of $\mathcal H$ should be at most 1?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What parts are you having trouble with?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I second what @Omnomnomnom said. Also problem 3 is formulated weirdly as the map $H$ is defined via itself (which surely isn't right)  - there most likely will be some clarification needed here.

Comment: @Frederikv.E. yes I was going to write my solution, but the library closed so right now I have no access to wifi for my pc and typing from my phone in latex is awful. If you were so kind to wait till tomorrow I'll write my question and solution in a proper way as soon as the library opens!

Comment: @Gitana it's not necessary to write your solution so far in full.  It's sufficient for you to summarize what you've done and explain where exactly you're stuck.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom i've edited the question adding my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding 1: you have incorrectly computed the inner product.  Note that
$$
\operatorname{tr}(AB^\dagger) = \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}\overline{b_{ij}}\right) = \sum_{i,j = 1}^n a_{ij}\overline{b_{ij}}
$$
This should make your work going forward easier.

Regarding 2: your set does not give a full base of the space.  To get a full basis, use the set $\{E_{ij}\}_{i,j = 1}^n$, where $E_{ij}$ is the matrix whose $i,j$ entry is $1$ and whose other entries are $0$.  It is useful to note that $E_{ij} = e_ie_j^\dagger$, where $e_1,\dots,e_n$ is the canonical basis of $\Bbb C^n$.

Regarding 3, consider the following:
$$
(\mathcal H(B),A) = (H^\dagger BH,A) = \operatorname{tr}(A[H^\dagger BH]^\dagger) = 
\operatorname{tr}(AH^\dagger B^\dagger H) =
\operatorname{tr}(HAH^\dagger B^\dagger)\\
= \operatorname{tr}([HAH^\dagger] B^\dagger)  = (B,HAH^\dagger)
$$

Regarding 4: Remember that in this context, the definition of the norm is
$$
\|B\|^2 = (B,B) = \operatorname{tr}(BB^\dagger)
$$

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to correct my solution! I still can't understand point 4. I know that the operator norm should be equal to $||B||$ as defined by the inner product. Is this the answer?

Comment: I just meant to point out that "$H$ preserves distances" is not a sufficient explanation.  Yes, $H$ preserves distances with respect to the Euclidean norm, but we have to show that it "preserves distances" in this new context,

Comment: ok got it! Thank you very much!